# Which one is better database design?

Tags: database-design

I am getting confused about Database Design. I am working as a developer in one of the companies and I had a discussion with my boss about the following issue in the database design. A part of the database design that I have to handle contains two tables:

```
Employees Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, OrganizationCode
Organizations Table: OrganizationCode, Name...
```

These two tables will take care of all the employees, departments, divisions and units in the company. Most of the databases designed by the other developer were designed in such a way there is no relationship between these two tables.

For me, I told my boss it is better to make a relationship between these two tables (which means the `OrganizationCode` is a foreign key to the primary key of Organizations table). Because it is going to be easy to enforce the constraints, integrity and also for writing the query.

He refused that without giving me a proper reason. We have more than 2000 employees in my department and around more than 50000 in the company. So I think the design that he recommended will take a huge space and it is going to be difficult to handle from the application development prospective.

**What do you recommend guys?**

Comment: It's not clear to me what the two alternative designs are. Is it your suggestion that the organisation code be added to the employee table? If so, what is the alternative suggestion, and why would the alternative take a huge space?

Comment: The two options are: Option #1: there is a relationship between the two tables. Option #2: there is no relationship.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a relationship between the tables"? Do you mean a constraint?

Comment: If the only difference between the two designs is a foreign key constraint, there's no difference in "space" (no difference in database size). There *might* be a slight difference in size due to supporting indexes.

Comment: @cat : After a little while of the system being in production, there **might** also be a slight difference in the correctness and accuracy of the data.  If the FK constraint actually applies to his case, that is to say, of course.

Comment: @ErwinSmout: Oh, no doubt about correctness and accuracy. I was commenting only on the perceived "huge space" requirement for enforcing foreign key constraints. (And I'm still not 100% sure the OP is talking about foreign key constraints. I'm not sure the OP knows, either.)

Answer (score 5):

Both you and your boss need to understand the difference between analysis and design.  The design of a relationship between the two tables is subordinate to the reality in the real world of the subject matter, and the information requirements on the database.

When you analyze the subject matter (the so-called "real world") from a data perspective, you divide the whole subject space into entities and relationships among those entities.  You then treat each value to be stored in the database as an instance of an attribute.  Each attribute describes some aspect of either an entity or a relationship.  Each attribute also has a domain, which is the set of possible values for that attribute.  All of this makes up a conceptual data model, and its features are discovered, not invented.

Then, when you go to make a database design, you design columns, tables, and foreign keys in the light of what you know about entities, relationships, and attributes.  You of course need to know how to make a good design, given a conceptual model and a few other details.

So, in your case,  what does the suject matter look like?  Do employees work in a department?  That's a relationship.  A department can have many employees working in it.  Can an employee work in more than one department?  If yes, then you have a many-to-many relationship.  If that's the case, you'll need a junction table containing two foreign keys.  If not, then your design will adequately reflect the many-to-one relationship.

By phrasing the question this way, in terms of the subject matter, you may be able to reach a common understanding with your boss about the structure of the real world.  Then, you may be able to reach a common understanding of how foreign keys can help represent that reality.  Or your boss might be content to leave database (re)design up to you, so long as s/he retains veto power over the conceptual model.

Answer (score 1):

Employees have to relate to organisation units in some way, and the question really is whether to preserve the history of that relationship or not. If you do not need to preserve the history then you can get away with the organisation code in the employee table, otherwise you need a join table between organisations and employees to show the history of the employee-department relationship.

Another consideration is whether to preserve the history of the inter-organisation relationships, which would need another join table.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is better than that of your boss. With your boss's design, it will be possible for employees to be linked to organizational units that do not exist. Updating organizational information will also be a pain, and these updates will have to occur in two locations.

In the current times, space is not really a big factor anymore, but maintainability of the system and ensuring that the data is correct should be the deciding factor to establish a proper relationship between the two tables.

If I were you, I would inquire as to why exactly your boss is against enforcing the relationship.